# How to use triggers in DJI-SDK?

Tags: dji-sdk

Does anyone know how to use DJI triggers for iOS?
Could anyone share with me some sample codes to understand triggers?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for now, I only found this api documentation to explain `DJIMissionTrigger`: https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/Components/Missions/DJIMissionTrigger.html?search=djitrigger&i=0&